# Xcode not running on mac os sierra high

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode9.1

I am using MACos on windows platform through VMware and I need Xcode for my next school project so I tried to download it and I downloaded version 9.1 of Xcode from a StackOverflow link and I have mac os high sierra running on my VMware but every time I try to open the Xcode it quits saying 'The operation could not be completed due to IDEdefferenceinItializationonError main error 1', please help me out of this, thanks

Comment: Are you certain you can run MacOS in a VM? I'm not sure that is a supported setup. If that's true all bets are off.

Comment: Yes, it is running in a VMware , through the guest operating system...

Comment: if you don't wanna answer then its ok but please don't discourage me from downvoting it, I ask the question because I really do not know the solution...

Comment: I did not down vote the question. Someone else did. I think the main issue is that MacOS running on VMware is not supported by Apple and therefore all the _tooling_ (like Xcode) on MacOS running on VMware is not supported. You might also want to continue searching the web for that specific error.

Comment: That may be the case but simply I cannot afford a MacBook for a project  so I tried this option, and I was not pointing to you that downvote thing, this question may be not up to the mark as some people want for this site but I asked what I had to ask, I will search for it and thanks for your suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error i finally found a solution that would solve this problem actually I just installed some tools my VMware wanted to have in that guest operation system(Mac OS) and some updates that appstore was showing to me and then I reinstalled the xcode(not to download again, just reinstall it from raw file) and after that all runs pretty good, so anyone facing this kind of situation should make the updates which the machine is asking for wheteher it be for MAC OS or VMware as on virtual machine everything matters... Thanks